# htaccess rewrites causing side affects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ /member/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^assets(/.*)?$  /member/assets$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^images(/.*)?$  /member/images$1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^php(/.*)?$  /member/php$1 [L]
```

The desired effect is:

```
https://example.com/username -> https://example.com/member/profile.php?user=$1
```

This works, however, the issue is there are 2 undesired outcomes happening from this.

**First:** `https://example.com` and `https://example.com/` return 404 errors but `https://example.com/index.php` works just fine.

**Second:** `https://example.com/username/` ends up forwarding to `https://example/member/php/?user=username` and returning a 404 error.

I have also attempted

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php
```

But this seems to have no effect on the issue

My actual desired end result would look more like:

```
https://example.com -> https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/ -> https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/username -> https://example.com/member/profile.php?user=$1
https://example.com/username/ -> https://example.com/member/profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? And this `.htaccess` is presumably in the document root?

Comment: No I have absolutely nothing else in the `.htaccess` file and yes this is in the `document root`.

Comment: If you comment out all your rewrite rules, does the root page use index.php?  I think there is something else going on because `^php(/.*)?$` shouldn't match the home page.

Comment: I have everything sorted except the regex. You asking about reverse proxies clued me in to 80% of my problems. However you also pointed out the regex will match everything, not jsut usernames (logically). How would I match all characters except those containing a period? For example match: `asdf, ASdf, AS$DF etc` and do not match `asdf.html, asadf.php, asdf.js, asdf.jpg etc` effectively not matching if it contains the period. If I can sort that I am good to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ /member/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
> ```

> **First:** `https://example.com` and `https://example.com/` return 404 errors but `https://domain.name/index.php` works just fine.

The first rule will catch the request (since it allows an empty URL-path) and will rewrite the request to `/member/profile.php?user=`. So, presumably it is your script that is triggering the 404?

In fact, it looks like you are missing a slash before `?` to match an optional trailing slash (ie. `/username` or `/username/`), rather than making the entire pattern optional! ie. `^([^/]+)/?$`

You would also need the `NS` (`nosubreq`) flag to prevent the subrequest by mod_dir for the `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.php`) also being caught by this rule. However, this rule is arguably matching too much, as it will also catch direct requests for `index.php` (and any other files you might have in the root). So, maybe you need to be more restrictive in what characters are allowed in *usernames*? For example, at a minimum, exclude dots (as well as slashes) with `^([^/.]+)/?$`? Or allow only letters and numbers (and underscores), eg. `^(\w+)/?$`. (`\w` is a shorthand character class that represents `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.)

Note that the first rule will also match `assets`, `images` and `php` - so these are valid usernames. Is that intentional? You could reverse the rules so this does not happen, but you would need to ensure that there are no usernames that match these strings.

NB: `https://example.com` and `https://example.com/` are exactly the same request. (The browser effectively appends the slash after the hostname to make a valid HTTP request. See the following question on the Webmasters stack: [Is trailing slash automagically added on click of home page URL in browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser))

> **Second:** `https://example.com/username/` ends up forwarding to `https://example.com/member/php/?user=username` and returning a 404 error.

I can't see how that would happen with the directives as posted. None of your rules would match `/username/` (with a trailing slash), unless the *username* is "assets", "images" or "php" - but that still wouldn't result in the stated rewrite? However, `/username/` would result in a 404 because nothing actually happens to rewrite the URL!

Your rules should perhaps be written like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ member/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^assets(/.*) member/assets$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images(/.*) member/images$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^php(/.*) member/php$1 [L]
```

The capturing subpattern in rules 2, 3 and 4 is not optional, so I've removed the trailing `?$`.

I've also removed the slash prefix on the substitution string, to make it a relative file-path.

Which could also be further "simplified" to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /member
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((assets|images|php)/.*) $1 [L]
```

Comment: This solves the latter half of my issue - ie getting both `/username` and `/username/` to work. However I still have the issue of the domain DirectoryIndex not working unless its directly called. This can't possible be a scripting error as the index page is literally pure html. If I remove that first rule, the front page works again, but the username rewrite fails.

Comment: @Bruce Ah yes, the rule will also match subrequests for `index.php` (by mod_dir). You would need the `NS` flag to prevent that. However, it will also match direct requests for `index.php` as well - so I'm not sure how that is currently working for you? What version of Apache are you using? Do you have a frontend proxy that is managing static file requests? Ideally, you would make the regex more restrictive. What characters do you permit in usernames? Currently, the rule matches anything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Bruce Direct requests for `.php` files might be proxied to the backend PHP engine (Fast/CGI) which effectively bypasses `.htaccess`.

Comment: "How would I match all characters except those containing a period?" - The previous update to my answer covered that scenario... "exclude dots `^([^/.]+)/?$?`" @Bruce